# RxJava Android threading boilerplate

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Few days ago I have faced with the treading rx problem. I was thinking how the rxJava threading works. This code didn't want to run on another thread.

```
     mAPIInterface.getAllProjects(accessToken)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Project>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    mView.showLoadProgress();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull List<Project> allProjects) {
                    projects = allProjects;
                    mView.hideLoadProgress();
                    mView.onProjectsLoaded();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    mView.hideLoadProgress();
                    mView.onProjectsLoadError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Then I have find the solution but I'm still not sure if it's ok. That's look like there are some more good solution:

```
     mAPIInterface.getAllProjects(accessToken)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .map(new Function<List<Project>, List<Project>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Project> apply(@NonNull List<Project> projects) throws Exception {
                    return projects;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Project>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    mView.showLoadProgress();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull List<Project> allProjects) {
                    projects = allProjects;
                    mView.hideLoadProgress();
                    mView.onProjectsLoaded();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    mView.hideLoadProgress();
                    mView.onProjectsLoadError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

With that `map()` middleware it works. But should I use that everytime when I need to run the process on another thread?

Comment: Could be more specific to your problem? Your first snippet looks fine to me. If you give more details then someone could be able to help.

Comment: Yeah, and it should be working. But Observable that I'm calling is running in UI thread.

Comment: could you try `Schedulers.io()`?

Comment: Sure, I have tried all the threads. And it still was running in UI thread. The problem has been fixed only with midleware (e.g. filter or map).

Comment: is `getAllProjects()` a network call? if yes then Which lib are you using?

Comment: Retrofit2. But the problem also appears with usual ObservableOnSubscrive<T> class

Comment: Did you receive NetworkOnMainThreadException? How did you determine that it's not running on other thread?

Comment: Yeah. And then data is not fetched. But, as I said it works if I'm adding some methods between subscribeOn and observeOn

Comment: @PavelSavchkov its not desirable behaviour. map is not used for that. Which version of rxJava are you using? i would suggested to use RxJava2.

Comment: @chandil03 I understand. Yeah, that's the version that I'm using (2.1.3)